# Rails returning brackets with haml output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am displaying a list of records on my page and each record has several sub categories.  I am displaying the title of the record and the related categories below it in a slightly smaller and lighter font.

For some reason, when the categories are displayed, the brackets are returned.  This is generated from a has_many :through relationship, so an array is returned.

Here is my haml in the view:

```
= location.services.map {|service| service.name }
```

Here is the result as displayed to the users:

```
["Plumbing", "House Repair", "Lawn Care"]
```

Please notice this is returned as if it is formatted as an array!  My end user's don't want to see data formatted as a hash or an array.

Do you see any reason this is happening?!

Comment: `My end user's don't want to see data formatted as a hash or an array.` lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because [map](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-map) return you an array in results. As you dont want to show an array to users, you can use `join` function on the returned array.

```
1.9.3-p429 :011 > res = ["Plumbing", "House Repair", "Lawn Care"]
1.9.3-p429 :013 > res.join(', ')
 => "Plumbing, House Repair, Lawn Care"
```

So you can just do:

```
location.services.map {|service| service.name }.join(', ')
```

or, you can also explore [to_sentence](http://apidock.com/rails/Array/to_sentence) of rails, which will give you more user friendly output:

```
location.services.map {|service| service.name }.to_sentence
# returns:  Plumbing, House Repair and Lawn Care
```

Comment: That did the trick! I wound up using .join(' ') to just have a space between the records.  Thanks again!